# composite index and integer comparison

Tags: mysql

Will col1,col2 two column index be used in following query?

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (val > col1 and val < col2)
```

Is there a good resource you could direct me to learn how to understand EXPLAIN results?

Comment: What's the actual question here? Do you just want to know what EXPLAIN results mean? If so, just check out the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html

Comment: Also check out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/range-optimization.html

Comment: I would be inclined to use `WHERE val between col1 and col2` instead - it reads better

Comment: @bohemian, my brain can't figure out what your suggestion does since col1 and col2 are the columns...

Comment: @AlainCollins These two conditions are identical: `(val >= col1 and val <= col2)` and `val between col1 and col2`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a composite index on (col1, col2) - or vise-versa, depending - would be used for the two comparisons in your query.